# Plotly not showing Intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, plotly

I am starting to learn about plotly but I have a question.I am using Intellij Idea Ultimate

1.Why plotly not working on python console?When using scientific mode we need to use python console debugger to see our data,but when using this debug mode the plotly not work,it only execute the data.But plotly work in Run file

2.Even with python console debugger the plot its not showed in my Intellij Plot Sciview

is this my mistake or a bug?Thanks

here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


df = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv')
df_clean = pd.read_csv('netflix_titles.csv')
df['date_added'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_added'], infer_datetime_format=True)
example = 'September 9, 2019'
pd.to_datetime(example, infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
df = df[['release_year', 'title', 'director', 'country', 'date_added', 
           'duration']].sort_values('release_year',ascending=True)
figf = px.pie(df, values='release_year', names='country')
figf.show()
```

[Plot not showing plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B6nz.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm and IntelliJ don't support plotly yet.

There is a feature request in its issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43407, feel free to vote and comment.